# marginpar inside captionof inside minipage

Tags: captions, minipage, marginpar

I really need to use `\marginpar` like in the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. 
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer 
id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{RedArrow.png}
\captionof{figure}{Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing 
vitae\marginpar{Lorem ipsum \ref{fig:RedArrow} dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit.}, felis. Cur- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit.}
\label{fig:RedArrow}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

But I just get errors. What can I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To remove the `! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }` error, you just put `\protect` in front of `\marginpar` (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227839/134574)). But then another error comes up: `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode`, which is intentionally programmed in `\marginpar`, so I don't think it's possible to do what you want without changing `\marginpar`... See if [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211803/134574) solves your problem.

Comment: Smells like an XY problem. I suggest you tell us what you really need to do and not the way you think you need to do it, because the former is very likely possible, whereas the latter is very likely impossible. What you think you need ain't going to work, but what you actually need probably would. Not knowing what you're trying to do, it's hard to suggest much more than trying not to really need it.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, @cfr: Thanks for your answers. I saw the link, but it uses a `figure` block. I am using a `minipage` block in order to put the figure and its caption aligned within an item inside an `itemize` block. The `figure` block seems to align the figure and its caption within the page width... Look [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/figure-with-caption-within-an-itemize-list-not-indenting-correctly)

Comment: If you use the short caption (add [] after {figure}) you get the more normal error message, "Not in outer par mode."  Which you aren't, inside a minipage.  Try marginnotes instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try `marginnotes`. I hope that it works...